# Custom ng-repeat using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to use `ng-repeat` to show my results, but the template is a little bit specific...

It works using EJS like this :

```
<% var i = 0; %>

<% vehicles.forEach(function(vehicle, index){ %>

<% if (i === 0) {%>
<div class="line">
<% } %>

<div class="col-3">
  <article>
    <img src="/uploads/<%-vehicle.thumbnail%>" alt="<%-vehicle.title%>">
    <h3><a href="/mes-vehicules/show/<%-vehicle.id%>"><%-vehicle.title%></a></h3>
    <p><%-shortText(vehicle.description, 50)%></p>
    <span><%-formatNumber(vehicle.priceTtc)%></span>
  </article>
</div>

<% if(i === 3) { %>
</div>
<div class="space-10"></div>
<% i = -1; %>
<% } %>

<% i++; %>

<% }); %>
```

Using AngularJS I'd like to know how to do, my code doesn't work...

```
<div class="line" ng-if="$index%3 == 0">
  <div class="col-3">
    <article>
      <img src="/uploads/{{vehicle.thumbnail}}" alt="{{vehicle.title}}">
      <h3><a href="/mes-vehicules/show/{{vehicle.id}}">{{vehicle.title}}</a></h3>
      <p>{{vehicle.description | short}}</p>
      <span>{{vehicle.priceTtc | formatNumber}}</span>
    </article>
  </div>
</div ng-if="$index%3 == 0">
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I think you'll want something like this: `ng-class="{  line: $index%3 = 0 }"` instead of an `ng-if`

Comment: One option is to split the array of vehicles in your controller

Comment: That was the solution. I splited the array and it works... But my filter doesn't work on the first `ng-repeat`...

Comment: @tonymx227, you don't need to use `ng-if` to close your `div`, it's already on top... also post your filter..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want 4 childs in one div whose class should be 'line' & after every four items you want to insert one div whose class is 'space-10'. This is possible by using `ng-if` & by checking if $index is multiple of 4.

For displaying maximum 50 characters,we have to create a `shortText(desc,length)` function in our controller which will return us shortened text.

For formatting number, Angular js provides `number` filter.

**HTML Code:**

```
  <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
   <div class="line" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0">
      <div class="col-3"">
        <article>
          <img src="/uploads/{{vehicle.thumbnail}}" alt="{{vehicle.title}}">
          <h3><a href="/mes-vehicules/show/{{vehicle.id}}">{{vehicle.title}}</a></h3>
          <p>{{shortText(vehicle.description, 50)}}</p>
          <span>{{vehicle.priceTtc | number}}</span>
        </article>
      </div>
    <div class="space-10" ng-if="$index % 4 == 3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$scope.shortText= function(desc,length) {
             if(desc.length>length)
return desc.substr(0,length);
else
return desc;
  }
```